# Emberjs - How to map api json response to a model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

While trying to build an Ember.js sample application, to call a REST Api and display results. I was able to call, fetch and display the results. In the component I am reading through the json response results.

How can I map the `response data` to a pre-defined model and use that in the component instead? I could not find relevant docs at https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/defining-models/ or https://guides.emberjs.com/release/in-depth-topics/making-api-requests/#toc_where-to-make-api-requests

Code details:

1. Using this sample API https://reqres.in/api/users
2. Model: (--update--)

```
export default class UserModel extends Model {
  @attr('string') id;
  @attr('string') firstname;
  @attr('string') lastname;
  @attr('string') email;
  @attr('string') avatar;
}
```

3. Route:

```
export default class UsersRoute extends Route {
  async model() {
    let response = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users');
    let data = await response.json();
    return data.data;
  }
}
```

4. Template:

```
<UserList
  @title="List of Users"
  @users={{@model}}
/>
```

5. Component:

```
{{#each @users as |user|}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
       <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
       <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
       <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

Comment: I guess you should have a look at https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/4.1/classes/JSONSerializer/

Answer (score 2):

Generate a user model:

`ember g model user`

```js
import Model, { attr } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class UserModel extends Model {
  @attr('string') email;
  @attr('string') firstName;
  @attr('string') lastName;
  @attr('string') avatar;
}
```

Generate an application adapter and serializer:

```
ember g adapter application
ember g serializer application
```

Add your API URL to the adapter:

```js
import JSONAPIAdapter from '@ember-data/adapter/json-api';

export default class ApplicationAdapter extends JSONAPIAdapter {
  host = 'https://reqres.in/api'; // the `users` part of the path is autogenerated based on the model name
}
```

Update the serializer:

```js
import JSONSerializer from '@ember-data/serializer/json'; // note that this is not the default serializer, JSONAPISerializer
import { underscore } from '@ember/string';

export default class ApplicationSerializer extends JSONSerializer {
  // specify underscore-formatted keys
  keyForAttribute(attr) {
    return underscore(attr);
  }

  // use the `data` property in the payload as the serializable response
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload = payload.data;
    return super.normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
  }
}
```

Update your route to use Ember Data methods instead of raw `fetch`:

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class UsersRoute extends Route {
  @service store;

  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('user');
  }
}
```

And finally you can then use the data (using camelcase-formatted attributes):

```
{{#each @users as |user|}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed message Charles. I was actually looking to manually map json response to a Model instead of making it automated. Usually json response has several elements, we need to pick & choose certain key-values from there to build the Model.

Comment: Also when I tried the above, page is empty. Error in console: "GET http://localhost:4200/users 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @SurenKonathala hmmm.. that's a bit against the ember way of doing things. In theory you can make a `fetch` call and then just use the `store.createRecord('user', {name: data.name, etc}` but i honestly don't see any reason of doing that: you have the response which is formatted *almost* for the JSONSerializer, so I'd totally go with the Charles' suggestion here at the 1st glance

Comment: @SurenKonathala re the 404 - you should adjust your adapter to point it to the `https://reqres.in/api` and then when you do the users fetch it'd do the `https://reqres.in/api/users`

Comment: @SurenKonathala Can you give me some more information on your data source? Also make sure you've updated the adapter host like I've directed. Otherwise it'll default to `localhost:4200` or wherever your Ember dev server is running

Comment: @CharlesFries I have the sample implementation at https://github.com/ksurendra/ember-rest-samples . A of now writing directly from response and not mapping to model.

Comment: @SurenKonathala Typo in the name of your adapter file. It should be called `application.js` and not `applications.js`